# ASP.NET Core React.js app exposes its source code after being published to Azure

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm publishing an app created using the ***ASP.NET Core React.js*** template to ***Azure App Service***. However, after publishing, I can see all the source code in the browser without any obfuscation or other protective measures. I haven't made any changes to the settings, as it's a pure code from the template.

[image: DevTools Screenshot]

Does anyone know what's going on and what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

I have read the documentation from Microsoft and have tried searching for a solution to the problem, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: That's how it works, the code needs to run on the browser, so yes you'll see it by default.  You can likely find and run obsfucation tools as part of the build pipeline, but please don't think that's any form of security.  Minimisation of the JS is common but that's for performance reasons.

Comment: One second. I'm confused. Why is React.js code published to production if browsers don't understand its syntax? And if that's the case, why can't I see the same for example on this https://react-redux.realworld.io website?

Comment: Browser do understand JS and React is just JS, and you can see it in that example site.

Comment: So you mean that
\`\`\`javascript
render()
{
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => {
            const { element, ...rest } = route;
            return <Route key={index} {...rest} element={element} />;
          })}
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    );
}
\`\`\`
the browser can understand and run this html(react components) tags inside js code without extra "compilation" step ?

Comment: React syntax is compiled into ECMAScript which is run by browser. sourcemaps usually used for development purposes, when js hits breakpoint, for example, it will trigger breakpoint in react file

Comment: If this is a security concern then the common approach to address it, is that anything like that is handled via a server side process and the browser just interacts with it via API calls.  The browser code is then just UI/UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and thank you all for your answers.

The problem was in the '**js map**' files. To solve the problem, you just  need to add

`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to your **.env** file.

For more information, you can read this article : https://izhan-yameen25.medium.com/protect-your-react-js-source-code-in-production-build-e6b408003817

Comment: Yes, that is it. In addition, the .map file is requested by the .js file itself. If you look at the .js files produces, there is something like `//# sourceMappingURL=787.4fcda856.chunk.js.map`. You can include/remove that line accordingly as well.

Comment: careful, the map assists in 'translating' the code to make it easier to debug within the browser.  turning off the map does NOT stop the code being available to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language that is run on the client, so the code will be visible, however there are ways to bundle and minify the code so its smaller in size, which increases performance, this also obfuscates the code to a degree, but the code will always be available somehow.

see more on bundling and minification here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-7.0